# iOS6: UIViewController was unable to load nib named

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, ios6

When testing in the `iOS6` simulator, I am getting the following error when clicking a disclosure indicator:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] was unable to load a nib named "LocationDetail"'
```

It runs perfectly fine in `iOS5`.

I do NOT have the LocationDetail nib anymore, nor need to use it. I have looked in my entire project for references to it, as well as in my MainWindow nib and all connections looking to see where it could be used, but I find none.

How would XCode still be wanting to load this, and why only the errors in `iOS6`?

Comment: Do you have a `LocationDetailViewController` class still?

Comment: Yeah I do, and still use it. I create it using: LocationDetail *detail = [[LocationDetail alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];  Inside the .m there are no methods for loading nib files or anything. No reference to LocationDetail nib.

Comment: Look in Copy Bundle Resources in the Build Phases tab and see if that xib file is still present there. If so, you can delete it from there.

Comment: It isn't.  So, I decided to just rename my class and .h and .m files and that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not in Xcode, but in the iOS Simulator. If you've removed all references to the .xib in your project, and cleaned everything as you described, the problem is that the .xib file still exists in the app bundle *in the Simulator*. You should try deleting the app from the Simulator (or better yet, Reset All Content & Settings on the Simulator). This will fix it.

Answer (score 1):

what i know is that initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped will call the initWithNibName:Bundle: method...

your class had the same name as your nib file, so when you called the initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped it tried to load that nib file.

when you renamed your class, it didn't find an nib with the same class name so no errors showed up as before.

Comment: Yeah, but the nib file had been deleted. Long gone!

Comment: i had a similar issue before... what i did then is i perform clean (Product -> Clean) and usually it fixes my issues with deleted files.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to just rename my class and .h and .m files and that fixed the issue.

Who knows why.

Comment: It triggered a recompile of your implementation file. ;)

Comment: Good thing. Still can't figure out how it knew about my old nib.

Comment: Probably some default nib loading behavior - like if you do `[[MyViewController alloc] init]` it looks for `MyViewController.xib` by default.

Comment: No, but initWithNibName:nil will :) @CarlVeazey

Comment: I never implemented initWithNibName:nil :(

Comment: The default implementation is provided by `UIViewController` ;)

Comment: @borrrden fair enough but init calls initWithNibName:nil